# In terms of communication with a computer with the receiver in a glider, is there a certain frequency I should consider?

Tags: data-link

I am part of a university team of engineers that design and manufacture a plane. My sub-team is in charge of designing an autonomous glider that needs to deploy from the plane and land in a given zone.

Here is my question. In terms of communication with a computer with the receiver in the glider, is there a certain frequency I should consider for proper communication? Or is it not needed at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about radio or computer communications than aviation.  Perhaps it can be migrated to Amateur Radio.SE or one of the computer stacks?

Comment: It would make most sense to use frequencies already allocated to drones. Even if you are not controlling the glider remotely, many drones already send information back to base (such as pictures) and it probably makes sense to follow the same protocols.

Comment: Question may be clearer if you include what communications are being done, and expand on the drone's classifications. [UAV/ROV, whatever] Mentioning what countries it will be run in may also impact answers. I would be wary about kicking this over to non-aviation stacks too quickly, as there are some rather distinct differences between communicating between two boxes on land, and between things flying... Especially if coms relate to the device's safety.

Comment: considering a frequency is very important, depending on which frequency you use and the power available the result can be from "everything works great" to "armed people come to you and take away your toys"

Comment: @Chris - Are you asking which aviation frequencies to avoid so that you don't conflict with aircraft comms?